# Fetching of non-public @android images

Tags: android, android-image

Where do you get from non-public Android images as we cannot use them as reference. 
For example @android:drawable/call_contact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get those images in your android installation directory.
In my computer you can get images from below path

```
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-8\data\res\drawable-hdpi
```

Thanks
Deepak