# Storing Android system icons in my own app

Tags: android, icons, android-source

I've read that the references to the android system icons aren't fixed / could be changed and therefore it would be better to save them as a resource of your application. I once found a guide showing how to get the icons from the android repository but I can't find it again.
So my question is: How do I get the android system icons from the repository? Which path are they in? I am confused by all the git files and stuff on https://android.googlesource.com

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177462/fetching-of-non-public-android-images/6177572#6177572

Comment: Yes and no. The thread doesn't include the correct solution, the ldpi folder is missing (probably depends on where you got the source)

Comment: Yes you are right. But if you know about path of hdpi its not that difficult to get the path of mdpi or ldpi.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Android built-in system resources are stored with your Android SDK under

```
<SDK_path>/platforms/android-<API_version>/data/res
```

Since you want an icon, you should look into various `drawable` subfolders there and take the images you'd like to use.

Comment: oh great, didn't even know they are also on my hard disk :-) thank you very much!

Comment: update: unfortunately I am missing drawable-ldpi ): As far as I can remeber they were in the repo, but I don't have them on my HDD.

Comment: update 2: I found the link I mentioned: http://blog.vertile.com/nathan/2011/02/default-android-menu-icons-in-your-app/

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf Now link is http://nathan.vertile.com/default-android-menu-icons-in-your-app/